# No flux boundary condition on PDE on surface (Laplace-Beltrami)

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

What would a Neumann BC on a PDE posed on a surface look like? In the flat case, we have
$\nabla u \cdot N = 0$ 
where $u$ is the solution of the PDE and $N$ is unit normal vector.

In a surface case, what would it be? Would it involve a conormal vector instead? Would I use Laplace-Beltrami operator instead? Would appreciate any explanations.

Comment: If the surface is oriented, then you can find a unique vector field normalized in the boundary of the surface, that is normal to the tangent space of the boundary in every point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Tomás said the normal is well-defined. There are many types of Neumann boundary condition that can be naturally imposed for Hodge Laplacian operator for a harmonic form $u$. Let $\newcommand{\d}{\mathrm{d}}\d$ and $\newcommand{\de}{\delta}\de$ be the exterior derivative and its codifferential, $\wedge$ and $\vee$ be the exterior and interior product. $n$ is the unit normal vector.

Neumann boundary value could be imposed on the following quantities:
$$
n\wedge \de u, \;\;n\vee \d u,\;\;n\vee \de u,\;\; n\wedge \d u.
$$
Translated into a smooth domain in $\mathbb{R}^3$ using curl and divergence for a $1$-form $u$:
$$
\nabla_{\Gamma} \cdot u,\;\; n\cdot (\nabla \times u),\;\; \nabla_{\perp}\cdot u,\;\; n\times(\nabla \times u),
$$
where the first and the third are surface divergence and divergence of the the normal part of $u$ respectively. <s>Applications would be the boundary value problems for the Maxwell system</s>.

The reference I gave was wrong. The correct reference is [Finite element methods for surface PDEs](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/staff/C.M.Elliott/DziEll13a.pdf). For example, the integration by parts formula involving co-normal (Theorem 2.10).